# removing extra space from top and left when using formitems in flex

Tags: forms, apache-flex, mobile

I want to remove the extra space/padding/gap from FormItem I,m using in form for a mobile project in flex 4.6

I have tried making gap and padding to 0 but there the form and it's fields are still have indent to the right and top ?

```
                <s:FormItem label="Start Date" width="150">
                    <s:HGroup>
                        <s:TextInput id="startDate" width="90" editable="false"/>
                        <s:Button id="setStartDate" label="set" height="34" fontSize="10" click="setStartDate_clickHandler(event)"/>
                    </s:HGroup>
                </s:FormItem>

                <s:FormItem label="End Date" width="150">
                    <s:HGroup>
                        <s:TextInput id="endDate" width="90" editable="false"/>
                        <s:Button id="setEndDate" label="set" height="34" fontSize="10" click="setEndDate_clickHandler(event)"/>
                    </s:HGroup>
                </s:FormItem>

            </s:HGroup>

        </s:Form>
```

Comment: Can you post some code & screenshots?

Comment: added code to the bottom of the question

Comment: Are you talking about the gaps between the two formItems? or the content of the Hgroup within the form item?

Comment: Yes, and also extra space at top and left b/w the first FormItem and the form container.

Answer (score 0):

1. Gap between two form items, **verticalGap**.(set it on Form container)
2. Default hgroup gap is 6, set it to 0.
3. If gap between two items withn the FormItem, **verticalGap** (set this on the form container)
4. Form has FormHeading, set paddingTop=0 on this FormHeading comp. Also, try to set the height of this to 0 and PaddingTop = 0 on the form to reduce the gap btwn the first element and the top of the Form container.

This has good information about it http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layouts_08.html

Comment: Well I tried the mentioned properties but still no result . The link you gave is related to flex 3 I,m using flex 4.6 and I think it has different styling architecture.

Comment: Then i'm assuming you might have to write a skin class for that. Or check this link http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e973827a8e912ac2b325a4-8000.html they use formLayout, you can try that. give a gap and paddings in -ve integers and try.